# UIWebView copy/paste

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I have a single view application that only contains a web view and a text field which acts like an address bar. After selecting part of a web page, I want to push a button to copy it (all of the selection including text and pictures) and automatically paste it into another view.
I can add a button to the edit menu (although I don't know how to remove the copy and paste buttons), but I don't know how to get the selection.

I have tried to use gesture recognizers to do this but I cannot find a way to get the selection. I set my view controller as a `UIWebViewDelegate` and an `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and tried to implement `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded`, but they don't get called when starting selection. Do you know an example with something like this or at least point me in the good direction? Thank you!

```
UIMenuItem *menuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Copy String" action:@selector(stringFromSelection:)];
UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
menuController.menuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:menuItem];

-(void)stringFromSelection:(id)sender
{
NSString *selectionString = [browserView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection()"];    //browserView is UIWebView class
NSLog(@"selected string = %@",selectionString);
}
```

Comment: did you try `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection()"];` ?

Comment: can i get selected text using javascript

Comment: @Malek_Jundi Just tried that, but my app crashes:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIMenuController stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a9ee80'

Comment: UIMenuController ? make sure that you are using webView instance .. for ex. in your viewController self.webView ? feel free to ask me in case you cant do it.

Comment: @Malek_Jundi fixed error. however the nslog command only shows "2012-05-21 15:25:42.373 MyApp[6352:f803] selected string = " instead of the text i selected

Comment: i think i understand why this happends. when i tap the "Copy String" button, the text gets deselected, so [browserView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection()"] returns nothing... i'll try adding a button to my view and trying to press that one instead of using menuItem...

Comment: use the `UIMenuController` .. its standard for such case.

Comment: @Malek_Jundi i am using `UIMenuController` but that doesn't return anything(i am adding an UIMenuItem to the UIMenuController to add a button to copy the string)...neither does using a separate button(the selection doesn't get cleared but still my `selectionString` returns nothing)...i have updated the original question to include the method where i try to get the string and where i add the menu item to the menuController

Comment: ok since you are using the `UIMenuController` why you don't just use the built-in copy method in iOS ?

Comment: @Malek_Jundi I will also use the built in copy button (for example if user wants to copy a part of an URL to paste in the address bar), so i need another button to copy the selection and automatically paste it in another view(also a custom button is more intuitive for the user). And even if i use the built-in copy, how do i programatically paste it(without user input for the paste action)?

Comment: ok make a dummy UIMenuItem for ex.Copy2 .. and inside its action try the javascript function .. if window.getSelection didn't work , try document.getSelection

Comment: @Malek_Jundi that's exactly what i did in the code above (in the original question) and it doesn't work...

Comment: try it like this `window.getSelection().toString()`

Comment: @Malek_Jundi 10x! that worked! tomorrow i will also test and see if i can get it to work with pictures to. please copy your answer in an answer thread so i can mark my question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution to get the selected text and copy it to add `.ToString()` to your function .. finally it will be :

```
-(void)stringFromSelection:(id)sender
{
NSString *selectionString = [browserView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().ToString()"];
NSLog(@"selected string = %@",selectionString);
}
```

am not sure if this will work with images also .. test it.